# How can I use Like query in SQLite android

Tags: android, sqlite

Can anyone tell me how to use LIKE command in android SQLite?. Example I have a table with 3 columns Name, Email and Position and I want to get yahoo Email addresses in Email column.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the enormously long method:

```
SQLiteQueryBuilder.buildQueryString(boolean distinct, String tables, String[] columns, String where, String groupBy, String having, String orderBy, String limit)
```

And in the `String where` set it to a string similar to `"column_name LIKE pattern"`
Note that you don't (and can't) include the word "where" in this string because it is going to be built into it.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteQueryBuilder.html